# Python - How to Remove Words That Started With Number and Contain Period

Tags: python, regex, string, space

What is the best way to remove words in a string that start with numbers and contain periods in Python?

```
this_string = 'lorum3 ipsum 15.2.3.9.7 bar foo 1. v more text 46 2. here and even more text here v7.8.989'
```

If I use Regex:

```
re.sub('[0-9]*\.\w*', '', this_string)
```

The result will be:

```
'lorum3 ipsum  bar foo  v more text 46  here and even more text here v'
```

I'm expecting the word `v7.8.989` not to be removed, since it's started with a letter.

It will be great if the removed words aren't adding the unneeded space. My Regex code above still adds space.

Comment: What's the point of the `s?` in your regex?

Comment: Isn't used for anything that matches a single whitespace character?

Comment: that would be `\s`

Comment: What do you want to do with something like `1.2.3c`?

Comment: If I use `\s`, it will only remove the first 2 parts of the number. But if I use `s?`, it will remove all the words that contain numbers and periods.

Comment: `s?` means 0 or more `s` characters, so it's effectively doing nothing

Comment: Ah, I see. I will edit the question.

Comment: 1.2.3c -> it shouldn't be removed also. I need the words that contain number and period which should be removed. Other than that, it should keep in the string.

Comment: Use a *word boundary*, `\b`, in the regex, to indicate "at this point in the matching, we must be at either the beginning or end of a word". By putting `\b` before and after some chunk of the regex, we can match a word that matches that chunk. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there are multiple word boundaries inside `15.2.3.9.7` so that duplicate is not relevant to this question

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If I use `\b`, the result will be -> `lorum3 ipsum  bar foo  v more text 46  here and even more text here v7` Notes that the numbers after v7 will be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the strings you want to remove:

```
(?:^|\s)[0-9]+\.[0-9.]*(?=\s|$)
```

It matches:

- `(?:^|\s)` : beginning of string or whitespace
- `[0-9]+` : at least one digit
- `\.` : a period
- `[0-9.]*` : some number of digits and periods
- `(?=\s|$)` : a lookahead to assert end of string or whitespace

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67Jwdn/2)

You can then replace any matches with the empty string. In python

```py
this_string = 'lorum3 ipsum 15.2.3.9.7 bar foo 1. v more text 46 2. here and even more text here v7.8.989 and also 1.2.3c as well'
result = re.sub(r'(?:^|\s)[0-9]+\.[0-9.]*(?=\s|$)', '', this_string)
```

Output:

```
lorum3 ipsum bar foo v more text 46 here and even more text here v7.8.989 and also 1.2.3c as well
```

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.

Comment: `(..., '', 0, re.I)` Can you explain what is the need for using 0 and re.I parameter?

Comment: @Gedanggoreng sorry - they're not required. When I thought you wanted to match `1.2.3c` I put them in so the regex would be case-insensitive. I've edited them out

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make use of a lookbehind, you can match the numbers and replace with an empty string:

```
(?<!\S)\d+\.[\d.]*(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+\.[\d.]*` Match 1+ digits, then a dot followed by optional digits or dots
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPG6VX/1)

If you want to match an optional leading whitespace char:

```
\s?(?<!\S)\d+\.[\d.]*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cuYtgV/1)

Comment: Well given that two incorrect answers have been upvoted the least I can do is bring yours in line...

Comment: @Gedanggoreng this is a better answer, you should accept it instead.

Comment: @Nick Its all good, I am on a holiday..woke up, quickly posted an answer and went to the beach. Now that I have some time reading all the answers, your answer looks fine to me.

Comment: Sure, it's fine, but not as optimal as this.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I really start appreciating a keyboard doing this on a mobile phone

Comment: That just makes it even more impressive! :) enjoy your break.

Comment: Thank you, it's working great. @Nick Are you sure it's better to accept this answer?

Comment: @Gedanggoreng up to you. I improved my answer (removing a lookahead that was left over from the letters time) so now they're pretty similar.

Comment: I think it's better to stay with @Nick's answer. I believe The fourth bird will not object with this.

Comment: @Gedanggoreng I don't object at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex, you can also do it using simple string operations:

```
res = ''.join(['' if (e.startswith(('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')) and '.' in e) else e+' ' for e in this_string.split()])
```

Comment: This removes `1.2.3c`, which is not supposed to be removed (see comments to question)

Comment: @Nick You are right. I think then we can simply extend this principle to exclude such cases too.

Comment: Go on then.....

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

`(^|\s)\d[^\s]*\.+[^\s]*`

This matches strings like '7.a.0.1' which contains letter extra.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7tboGW/1).

Comment: This would remove `1.2.3c`, which is not supposed to be removed (see comments to question)